# SQL Server - Find Unique Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying and failing to write a script to return any unique combinations of job and suffix where the (oper = 20 and value = 0) and (oper > 20 and value = 1). Based on the data below there is only one instance, job 2 suffix 3. In this combination of job and suffix the oper 20 = 0 and the oper 40 = 1.

```
job suffix oper value

1    1       20    0

1    1       30    0

2    3       20    0

2    3       40    1

3    2       20    0

3    3       50    1
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT job
     , suffix
FROM t1
GROUP BY job
       , suffix
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN (oper = 20 and value = 0) OR (oper > 20 and value = 1) THEN suffix END) =  COUNT(*) 
   AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

[**Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3675/17)

Comment: I think if there was no oper > 20 for a particular job / suffix combination this would return the job / suffix as a match

Comment: @user3673417 : Actually, it returned nothing when I tried it )

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is as a "set-within-sets" subquery.  A flexible approach to solving these is using `group by` and `having`.  In your case:

```
select t.job, t.suffix
from table t
group by t.job, t.suffix
having sum(case when oper = 20 and value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when oper > 20 and value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that match a specific condition.  So, the first ensure that there is at least one row where `oper = 20 and value = 0`.

Comment: @Notulysses . . . I fixed your SQL Fiddle so the data is correct and it now returns the correct results (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3675/1).  PS.  Thanks for putting the SQL Fiddle together.

Comment: My bad. I've wanted to help you by posting this fiddle but instead you've helped me).P.S. I've posted it not to show you that the answer is wrong, as I know it hardly ever is in your case.